# Robot Framework: Start Process with arguments on Windows?

Tags: robotframework

I'm quite new with Robot Framework, and I cannot find a way to run a process with arguments on windows. I am quite sure I did not understand the documentation and there is a simple way of doing that though...

Ok, let's say I can start my program using this command:

```
c:\myappdir>MyApp.exe /I ..\params\myAppParams.bin
```

How to do that in RF?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much :)

Edit 1:

Here is a piece of my code:

```
| *Setting*            | *Value*
| Resource             | compilationResource.robot 
#(Process lib is included in compilationResource)

#I removed the "|" for readability
...
TEST1
...
  ${REPLAYEXEDIR}=  get_replay_exe_dir #from a custom lib included in compilationResource
  ${EXEFULLPATH}= Join Path  ${WORKSPACEDIR}  ${REPLAYEXEDIR}  SDataProc.exe
  Should Exist  ${EXEFULLPATH}
  ${REPLAYLOGPATH}=  Join Path  ${WORKSPACEDIR}  ReplayLog.log
  ${REPLAYFILEPATH}=  Join Path  ${WORKSPACEDIR}  params  params.bin
  Should Exist  ${REPLAYFILEPATH}

  Start Process  ${EXEFULLPATH}  stderr=${REPLAYLOGPATH}  stdout=${REPLAYLOGPATH}  alias=replayjob
  Process Should Be Running  replayjob
  Terminate Process  replayjob                
  Process Should Be Stopped  replayjob
```

This works. As soon as I try to include the arguments like this:

```
  Start Process  ${EXEFULLPATH} ${/}I ${REPLAYFILEPATH}  stderr=${REPLAYLOGPATH}  stdout=${REPLAYLOGPATH}  alias=replayjob
```

I get this error:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

and this error comes from the start process line.

Let me know if I was unclear or if nmore info is needed.
Thank you all for your help on this.

Edit 2: SOLUTION

Each argument must be separated form the other (when not running in shell) with a double space. I was not using double spaces, hence the error.

```
|  | Start Process | ${EXEFULLPATH} | /I | ${REPLAYFILEPATH} | stderr=${REPLAYLOGPATH} | stdout=${REPLAYLOGPATH} | alias=replayjob
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To launch your program from a Robot Framework Test, use the [Process library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Process

*** Test Cases ***
First test
   Run Process  c:${/}myappdir${/}prog.py  /I  ..\params\myAppParams.bin 
   # and then do some tests....
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Laurent. However, I already tried that, and it didn'yt work. Please see my Edit 1.

Comment: Ok, I was missing the separator between the process, /I and the argumentfile path. Thank you very much. On the side, it shows that the double space separator is poorly readable. I'll stick to the "|" separator from now on. Merci encore Laurent

Comment: yeah, I tend to agree that double space separator can be confusing. On the other end, putting "|" everywhere make the tests a bit more heavyweight and it looks less like english sentences... Well, will keep thinking about it :-)

Comment: @Laurent Bristiel. This is not working on Ubuntu Server for me